# How to prefix a foreign key object to a model field in Wagtail admin?

Tags: django, drop-down-menu, wagtail, wagtail-admin

[image]

In this case, each feature **has one** Epic (models.Model)

```
epic = models.ForeignKey(Epic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
```

In the admin drop-down (and only there) I would like to show each item as:

epic.name - feature.name

Because some of my features have a similar name but different epics. I can't change the __ str __ function of the Feature model or it will affect the whole app.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to subclass Django's [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), and override the [label_from_instance](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/models.py#L1266-L1274) method that provides the label:

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class FeatureChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s - %s" % (obj.epic.name, obj.name)
```

You'll then need to [customise the edit form](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#customising-generated-forms) to use that custom form field type in place of the default ModelChoiceField:

```
from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminModelForm
# note - use WagtailAdminPageForm if this is a page model rather than a
# plain Django model managed through snippets / ModelAdmin

class ScopeForm(WagtailAdminModelForm):
    feature = FeatureChoiceField(queryset=Feature.objects.all())


class Scope(models.Model):
    # ...

    base_form_class = ScopeForm
```

Comment: works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Note that for a Page (and not any model), you need to use `WagtailAdminPageForm` instead.